# How to act atomically on a struct property?

Tags: swift, struct

Assume I have the following objects:

```
class Dog {
  let name: String
  var stats: Stats?
  func doSomething() { /*...*/ }
}

struct Stats {
  var weight: Double
  var age: Int
  func ageEquivalence() -> Int { /*...*/ }
}
```

... and that I want to perform some calculation on a `Dog` instance. I want to do this atomically, however. In other words, I want to guarantee that either *all* code is executed, or *no* code is executed.

To clarify the problem, first, let's assume that `Stats` were a `class`. In that case, this problem is easy to solve:

```
func updateAge(_ dog: Dog) {
  guard let stats = dog.stats else {
    return
  }

  stats.age += 1                            // A
  dog.doSomething()                         // B
  sendNotification(stats.ageEquivalence())  // C
}
```

It's either going to going to execute lines A-C if stats exists, or do nothing.

Now let's go back to the original problem, assume `Stats` is a `struct` again. If I try to run the code above, first I must change `let stats` to `var stats`, otherwise the compiler will complain that I'm trying to update a constant.

```
func updateAge(_ dog: Dog) {
  guard var stats = dog.stats else {
    return
  }

  stats.age += 1                            // A
  dog.doSomething()                         // B
  sendNotification(stats.ageEquivalence())  // C
}
```

But now we run in to the problem that `stats` is a copy of `dog.stats` so when I update the age on line A, I'm not actually modifying the original dog's age.

Our next approach might look like this:

```
func updateAge(_ dog: Dog) {
  dog.stats?.age += 1                         // A
  dog.doSomething()                           // B
  if let stats = dog.stats {
    sendNotification(stats.ageEquivalence())  // C
  }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that if `doSomething` has a side effect which sets `stats = nil`, we would have run lines A & B, but not the C.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

---

It seems that the crux of the problem is this line:

```
dog.stats?.age += 1
```

In order to modify a `struct`, we must act on the original object, meaning we must use [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html). This cannot be used in conjunction with a `guard var` since that would create a copy of the original `struct`, and the original `struct` might be changed due to a side effect at any point of the execution.

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: why is `updateAge(_:)` not an instance method on `Dog`?